# Instancing TubeGeometry in three.js

Tags: three.js

I have thousands of boxes (BoxGeometry) synced on a map: http://jsfiddle.net/hs2jbbo0/92/

I'd like to connect them with 3d lines (`TubeGeometry`?)
but potentially I'll have thousands of those lines so I thought maybe using instancing for them as well.
Is that possible with a `TubeGeomtry`?
If not, can this be done with a simple `BoxGeometry` with a fixed width
such that it looks 3d? (A simple `Line` is not helping here since it's width is always 1 in webgl).

Comment: FYI see https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/11349

Comment: Nice! Is it possible to extrude it? I was referring to a width in terms of 3d space

Comment: You can use `TubeGeometry` with instancing.

Comment: But each curve is different, how can I instance them by providing a different curve?

Comment: Sorry, I meant you can use `CylinderBufferGeometry` with instancing (for straight tubes).